# What are names for territories in space?

Tags: space, names

So in my universe the galaxy is divided up into cubical volumes of space of 50, 500, 5000, and 50000 light years (roughly it's actually divided into my own unit types, but they're roughly equal). There are 1000 of the previous areas in the next area up.

Currently I'm calling them Sectors, Blocks, Grids, and Octants, but that doesn't work, nor does "Quadrant" for the last one, especially since a sector really applies to any area of space in reality so the 50000ly area can be called a sector as much as the 50ly area.

So what are some other names for areas like this?

I'm talking about titles like sector, zone, territory, region, etc. None of those fit and I'm sure I am missing more and limiting my scope of thinking largely due to star trek. I'm not looking for made up words.

Comment: Those voting to close this question are in the wrong v.v This is no more story driven than asking "What are titles for heads of state" I am asking the same damn question save for it being with regard to territory rather than the leader of said territory.

Comment: While you're correct that this isn't story-based, there also isn't a definitive answer. You are free to devise whatever naming scheme you want, as long as you're consistent.

Comment: @Frostfyre I am asking for synonym words that are used today in the real world. Not to make shit up. That should be obvious. Just like the guy who asked about "what are title for heads of state" wasn't asking for how to make shit up, but what were the actual titles used, because if that person and I wanted to make it up we wouldn't ask. This question compeltely follows the rules and is a legit question so it would be much appreciated that you'd stop your nonsense.

Comment: If word choice is what you're after, you may be better off looking at threads like [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63876/better-word-than-district) on the English stackexchange

Comment: @Kys While that is a nice place, that doesn't answer the question as I'm not asking for specifically English, this is the right place to ask, as shown by the question I'm referencing,  and I'm getting sick of this. It's the same few people every time that keep doing it and they're 100% in the wrong. It's not even a "Oh I can see your point" type thing, They're simply wrong and seemingly judging by the fact that there is information that is relevant to help contextualize what is being looked for, but not being asked about.

Comment: @Durakken: "*I am asking for synonym words that are used today in the real world.*" We have a thesaurus for that sort of thing. "*They're simply wrong and seemingly judging by the fact that there is information that is relevant to help contextualize what is being looked for, but not being asked about.*" Your question was not closed as being "too story driven". It was closed as being "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Perhaps you should define what you find inadequate about "region", "sector", and "zone". These names are common in other works of science fiction. Explaining your reasoning for not picking these would put some constraints on what you're looking for and allow answers to be impartially judged.

Comment: @Durakken: "*thesauruses still rely on you trying to come up with a relatively close word and then going through all possible terms without missing them.*" So... you want us to do that for you? The problem, as you've outlined it, can be solved by 5-10 minutes of research on the web. It's not a problem of world-building; it's just the English Language.

Comment: @Kys There is nothing wrong with them in a certain sense, but "region and zone" are more for talking an unspecified random area that has a certain quality like "this is the dog zone" rather than "this is a zone" And I plan on using sector though I'm not sure how yet.

Comment: @NicolBolas No. I always thoroughly look for information before I ever ask other people because other people are always "just make it up" or do this type of BS. So no it can't be solved with a 5-10 minute research on the web. And AGAIN I'm not just looking for english terms. And if either were the case that those reasons mean this should be closed then thousands of other questions should be on this site that are not.

Comment: There's no reason to become hostile, Durakken. You aren't doing yourself any service by using expletives in response to people explaining themselves. The problem remains that we don't understand what's wrong with the terms defined already. You say you don't want English words, but what do you want? French equivalents of English words? German? Chinese? Pig Latin?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to apply a real/present world name to your areas?

If not how about something like a 'Dividium'?  As in "Control of the largest dividium in the galaxy is currently held by..."

Comment: I'm talking about titles like sector, zone, territory, region, etc. None of those fit and I'm sure I am missing more and limiting my scope of thinking largely due to star trek. I'm not looking for made up words.   Also you should avoid answers like these as they'll get voted down or deleted for not being answer, though I understand since you don't have 100 rep yet.

Comment: I'm not sure how my response isn't an answer as it provides a name for a territory which is what you asked for; It doesn't make sense that an answer should contain more information than requested.
Can understand not wanting any made up names to keep it realistic although I would suggest putting that in your question what with this being worldbuilding and the creating of worlds and names being central to that. 

With all of that in mind though some that come to mind would be:
Span, Dominion, Belt (Obviously dependant on the area shape) or Expanse

Comment: It's because of the beginning question, and the short answer that is phrased as a question. It also looks opinion based and story based when you make stuff up... and the length which people often have a problem with... I also the way you answered is unclear as to whether you made that up or it's an actual word

Comment: The beginning part of my answer is necessary due to the point I made not being clear in your question, without asking or mentioning it how would anyone know if you are only looking for real words? 
It's very clear that the second part is made up as it's preceded by the "Are you looking for real? No well how about this?". If that isn't clear that isn't my fault.

Comment: It looks like you asking about "proper names" rather than "what we call that area" I figured it out after a few read throughs, but it can be confused as such. The question should have been in a comment, but you can't so, as I said, I understand why you didn't do that.